# Want To bulkify the trigger error message Its now hard coded N I am not getting any clue for it

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger OppNConAcitityCounter on Task (after insert, after update) {
    List<Task> conc = new List<Task>();
    List<Task> opp = new List<Task>();
    set<id> conid= new set<id>();
    set<id> opid= new set<id>();

    task pp1= new task();
    integer count=0;
    integer count1=0; 
    for(Task tt:trigger.new){

        conid.add(tt.whoid); 
        opid.add(tt.WhatId);

    }
    System.debug('@@@@@@con'+conid.size());
    System.debug('@@@@@@op'+opid.size()); 

    conc= [select id,status from Task where whoid=:conid and who.type = 
    'contact' and Status!='Completed'];
    system.debug('@@@@@@@PA'+conc.size());
    for(Task p:conc){
        if(p.Status!='Completed'){
            count++;
        }
    }

    opp=[select id, status from Task where whatid=:opid and what.type = 
  'Opportunities__c'  and Status!='Completed' ]; 
    for(Task jj:opp){
        if(jj.Status!='Completed'){
            count1++;
        }  

    }


    List<contact> ll = new  List<contact>();
    List<contact> c = [select id from Contact where id=:conid ];
    //Contact cc = new Contact();
    for(Contact cc:c){
        cc.Total_No_Of_Activity1__c=count; 
        ll.add(cc);
        //cc.addError('Check');
    }
    if(ll.size()>0){
        try{
            update ll;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           List<task> ts= new List<Task>();

           trigger.new[0].adderror('If Lead status is Open or Working then Open task must be here');
           // Instead of zero I want system to pass its value

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back to edit this question. It's very difficult to evaluate and share a good answer on a post that is just a vague title and a large code paste.

Comment: Being consistent in your code formatting (indentation, spacing, etc...) really does help people read your code and begin to understand it. Properly formatted code reduces the barrier for people who may want to help. When you're asking for help, making it as easy as possible to help you is generally a good thing. Sloppy formatting makes it appear that you don't care about your code, and makes me think that you won't care about the effort that I (or others) would put in to try to help you overcome the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation such as this [Built-In Exceptions and Common Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_builtin.htm)
 explains the additional methods that some exceptions have including those of the `DmlException` that can be thrown on an update. Change your try/catch to this:

```
try {
    update ll;
} catch(DmlException e) {
    // Use e.g. e.getNumDml() and e.getDmlMessage(i) to build the error logic
}
```